# A list of all Emacs keybindings for Mac OSX

Tags: macos, emacs

I recently found out that Mac has system wide keybindings based on Emacs, but have had difficulty finding a complete list of them. Anyone know of any resources for this?

I've been learning Vim, but might start with Emacs instead if the OSX functionality is greater than just the arrow key style navigation I've found so far.

Comment: Consider removing the OSX tag in your question, as those are the people most likely to vote to close or down-vote since they are not exactly your target audience for this type of a question.  Emacs users are *a little* more forgiving.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

For the full monty of key bindings in Emacs, you can start with `C-h b` (or, equivalently, `M-x describe-bindings`).  You can also check out [this terrifyingly long table of default bindings](http://wttools.sourceforge.net/emacs-stuff/emacs-keybindings.html).  That's probably way more than you want or need right now, though.

Here's a [list of default OSX system key bindings](https://web.archive.org/web/20220608192008/http://www.hcs.harvard.edu/%7Ejrus/Site/system-bindings.html).  The ones you're probably interested in are the `^ + LETTER` keys, many of which are analogous to Emacs bindings.

A post on [Irreal](http://irreal.org/blog/) about [Emacs Keybindings for Mac OS X](http://irreal.org/blog/?p=259) talks about this system, and points out that the Cocoa Text System is customizable, which would allow you to add additional Emacs bindings (or whatever else you like).  There's a link in the post that points to a keybindings file that creates a lot of those bindings.